# AngularJs: ng-click is not working with dropable directive

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to create a Dropable div, but after that I have a problem with ng-click. If I add dropable directive to an element, ng-click on it and children will not working.

Can anyone please help me to resolve it?

There is a example code. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaFvG (I forked and add ng-click for demo)

You can see that ng-click on "Hi 0", "Hi 1" is not working.

Comment: Consider this as an alternative : http://ganarajpr.github.io/angular-dragdrop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you gave the droppable directive an isolated scope. If you remove

```
scope: {}
```

it should work.

Comment: It's so awesome, but I still don't know why. Could you please help me to explain it?

Comment: When scope: {} is added to a directive it then has its own scope, isolated from the controller. You can still pass in model values, you can read more about that here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive